# Reflection.Emit Opcode for peeking at the stack?

Tags: clr, reflection.emit

Is there a way to look up into the stack via Reflection.Emit Opcodes? For example, let's say I want to push X, and then push Y, and then I need to get at the value of X...how do I go about that?

True, I could store y into a local variable, and then later load Y again, but that's a bit of a round-about way of going at it.

Comment: Round-about doesn't matter.  The jitter cuts the overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.  See [Reflection.Emit - access topmost-but-one item from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718003/reflection-emit-access-topmost-but-one-item-from-stack) for another related question.